# Bounding $\frac{q\left(x\right)}{q^{\prime}\left(x\right)\cdot x}$ for polynomial $q$ with finite non-negative coefficients that sum to 1

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Is there an easy enough way to show that for a polynomial $q(x)=\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_{p}x^{p}$ with $\gamma_{p}\ge0$ and $\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_{p}=1$ where there are finitely many non-zero $\gamma_{p}$, we have for $x>0$: $\frac{q\left(x\right)}{q^{\prime}\left(x\right)\cdot x}\ge\frac{1}{p_{\text{max}}}$?

I wrote explicitly $\frac{q\left(x\right)}{q^{\prime}\left(x\right)\cdot x}=\frac{\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_{p}x^{p}}{\sum_{p\ge2}p\gamma_{p}x^{p}}$, and argued that $\frac{1}{p_{\text{max}}}$ is indeed the limit at $x\rightarrow{\infty}$. Then showing that the expression is decreasing finishes the problem. I couldn't prove it is decreasing using the derivative. Alternatively, I have a feeling there is a more direct, algebraic, easy arguement to show $\frac{\sum_{p\ge2}\gamma_{p}x^{p}}{\sum_{p\ge2}p\gamma_{p}x^{p}}\ge\frac{1}{p_{\text{max}}}$. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : it's not difficult to show that the expression $q(x)-\frac{xq'(x)}{p_{max}}$ is increasing on $]0;+\infty[$ and worth $0$ when $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f(x) &\equiv \frac{q(x)}{xq'(x)} = \frac{\sum_{p\geq 2} \gamma_p x^p}{\sum_{p\geq 2} p\gamma_p x^p} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sum_{p\geq 2}c_p(x) p}, \qquad c_p(x) \equiv \frac{\gamma_p x^p}{\sum_{p\geq 2} \gamma_p x^p}, \; \sum_{p\geq 2} c_p(x) = 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{<p>_{c_p(x)}} 
\end{align}

So the expression you're interested in is the inverse of the average $p$ weighted by $c_p(x)$. A fundamental property of averages is that they lie between the min and max values of their elements. Hence,
$$\frac{1}{p_{\max}} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{p_{\min}}$$

Since $f(0)=\frac{1}{p_{\min}}, f(\infty) = \frac{1}{p_{\max}}$, these are also the tightest bounds for $f(x)$. An interesting implication of this analysis is that $\frac{xq'(x)}{q(x)}$ could be interpreted as the expectation of the order of the most dominant term in the polynomial expansion of $q(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for such a solution as well!